# Center img horizontaly and verticaly inside the div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put in the center of my div an image. I was trying to do it with position relative, vertical align, margin 0 auto: everything leads to nothing. Maybe You have some suggestions? (I'm not putting the css code for image, couz' nothing works that I used :( )

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="send">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="chair.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.send {   
    display: inline-block;   
    width: 350px;   height: 565px;  
    vertical-align: middle;   
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Well, what? How do you wanna center it? The image can be centered just with `.send {text-align: center;}`

Comment: You are right! Thanks :)

Comment: Awesome. Delete this question before it gets downvotes.